# Collect user input while imshow window is open

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

So I am working with three different image types of the same field of view. I have added extra key and click picks using the matplotlib backend. Everything is working except for the key_press that asks for user input. Whenever I type that key I get an EOF error and no opportunity to give the input.

```
line 140, in key_press
    self.specimen_number = input('Specimen Number: ')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I just need some way to collect input in order to save various subsets of the data.

```
class subset_Museum_data:
    def __init__(self, rgb, swir, swir_cr, mwir, mwir_cr, draw_number, sample_number):
        self.rgb = np.asarray(rgb)[:15333, :,:]
        self.swir = swir[:1380,:,:]
        self.swir_cr = swir_cr[:1380,:,:]
        self.mwir = mwir[:2362, :, :]
        self.mwir_cr = mwir_cr[:2362, :, :]
        self.draw_number = draw_number
        self.sample_number = sample_number
        self.click_count = 0 
        self.swir_bands = np.load('X:/Ballymore-Oakport_Project/Utility_files/Clipped_Bands_New.npy')
        self.mwir_bands = np.load('X:/Ballymore-Oakport_Project/Utility_files/MWIR_Clipped_Bands.npy')
        if self.swir.shape[-1] > 200:
            self.default = (172, 219, 244)
        else:
            self.default = (61, 129, 22)
        
        self.plot()
        
    class Window:
        def __init__(innerself, image):
            innerself.image = image
            innerself.fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
            im = ax.imshow(innerself.image)               
            plt.tick_params(
            axis='both',          # changes apply to the x-axis
            which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
            left =False,
            right = False,
            labelbottom =False, 
            labeltop =False, 
            labelleft =False, 
            labelright =False,
         
            bottom=False,      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
            top=False,         # ticks along the top edge are off
            )
            
            
    def reset(self):
        print('Reset all points')
        self.top_left = {}
        self.bottom_right = {}
        self.click_count = 0
        self.swir_subset = 0
        self.mwir_subset = 0
        self.swir_cr_subset = 0
        self.mwir_cr_subset = 0
        
        
        
        
        
    def transform(self, x, y):
        coord_set = {'rgb_x': int(x), 
                     'rgb_y': int(y),
                     'swir_x': int(x/self.rgb.shape[1] * self.swir.shape[1]) , 
                     'swir_y': int(y/self.rgb.shape[0] * self.swir.shape[0])
                     }
        return coord_set
    
    def transform_mwir(self, x, y):
        coord_set = {'rgb_x': int(x), 
                     'rgb_y': int(y),
                     'mwir_x': int(x/self.rgb.shape[1] * self.mwir.shape[1]) , 
                     'mwir_y': int(y/self.rgb.shape[0] * self.mwir.shape[0])
                     }
        return coord_set
        
    
    def onclick(self,event):
        if event.button == 1:
            #print(event.key)
            if event.key == 'shift':
                ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
                self.point = self.transform(ix, iy)
                plt.figure()
                plt.plot(self.swir_bands, self.swir_cr[self.point['swir_x'], self.point['swir_y']])
                self.point = {}
        elif event.button == 3:
            self.click_count += 1
            ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
            if self.click_count == 1:
                self.top_left = self.transform(ix, iy)
                self.top_leftmwir = self.transform_mwir(ix, iy)
            elif self.click_count == 2:
                self.bottom_right = self.transform(ix, iy)
                self.bottom_rightmwir = self.transform_mwir(ix, iy)
                              
                self.swir_subset = self.swir[self.top_left['swir_y']:self.bottom_right['swir_y'] , self.top_left['swir_x']:self.bottom_right['swir_x']]
                self.mwir_subset = self.mwir[self.top_leftmwir['mwir_y']:self.bottom_rightmwir['mwir_y'] , self.top_leftmwir['mwir_x']:self.bottom_rightmwir['mwir_x']]
                self.swir_cr_subset = self.swir_cr[self.top_left['swir_y']:self.bottom_right['swir_y'] , self.top_left['swir_x']:self.bottom_right['swir_x']]
                self.mwir_cr_subset = self.mwir_cr[self.top_leftmwir['mwir_y']:self.bottom_rightmwir['mwir_y'] , self.top_leftmwir['mwir_x']:self.bottom_rightmwir['mwir_x']]
                
                
#=======================Plot subfigure SWIR============================================================================================                
                
                
                sp.imshow(self.swir_subset)     
                sp.imshow(self.mwir_cr_subset)
                sp.imshow(self.swir_cr_subset)
#=======================Plot subfigure RGB============================================================================================              
                zoom_window = self.Window(self.rgb[self.top_left['rgb_y']:self.bottom_right['rgb_y'] , self.top_left['rgb_x']:self.bottom_right['rgb_x']])
                mouseZ = zoom_window.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onclick) 
                keyPZ = zoom_window.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.key_press)
                keyRZ = zoom_window.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_release_event', self.key_release)
            
            
            elif self.click_count == 3:
                self.reset()
                
        
    def key_press(self, event):
        self.specimen_number = ''
        if event.key == 'shift':
            pass
        if event.key == 'enter':
            plt.figure()
            plt.plot(self.swir_bands, np.mean(np.reshape(self.swir_cr_subset, (-1, self.swir_cr_subset.shape[-1] )), axis=0))
            plt.figure()
            plt.plot(self.mwir_bands, np.mean(np.reshape(self.mwir_cr_subset, (-1, self.mwir_cr_subset.shape[-1] )), axis=0))
        if event.key == 'z':
            while self.specimen_number == '':
                self.specimen_number = input('Specimen Number: ')
            print(self.specimen_number)
            print('This will save now once the code is written')
            
        if event.key =='c':
            self.reset()
            
    def plot(self):
        first_window = self.Window(self.rgb)
        mouse1 = first_window.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onclick) 
        keyP1 = first_window.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.key_press)
```

Comment: `input` is typically only used in console applications, not GUIs. If you're prompting the user for input, you could create a [dialog](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html) window with `askinteger()` and then use tkinter's `wait_window()` method to hold until the user closes the dialog. That way you can avoid blocking the GUI with a `while` loop!